# How to use (new) LinkedIn API from and with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, linkedin-api, deprecated

It seems that Rlinkedin is [deprecated](https://github.com/mpiccirilli/Rlinkedin/issues/25), that LinkedIn API has changed, and that LinkedIn does not provide a lot of informations for R users in [documentation for developers](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/). I don't understand why. For the moment, there are references only for Bash, NodeJS and Java...

Could anyone provide a very basic, recent and working example in R to begin with LinkedIn API? For instance, how to get profiles? This kind of example doesn't work:

```
url <- 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/reidhoffman/'
library(httr)
profile <- httr::GET(url)
```

Comment: anything that is possible in their Bash implementations (using the `curl` binary) is also possible using `httr::GET` or the `rvest::` package. You just need to use `httr::add_headers` appropriately to include your token and the other variables.

Comment: And while I'm not going through the whole thing (too much work at this time, sorry), it seems like you have to set up an "application" in order to create an "access token" required for their API. Seeing as how they control the API completely (and are not likely to want data-scraping the hard way), that may be your only option. (I could be wrong, just my quick interpretation of what I see.)